# How to start google app engine for sympy-gamma on windows local-host

Tags: python, django, localhost, sympy

I am using Windows 10 and I am completed all the process given by `sympy-gamma` document https://github.com/sympy/sympy_gamma/ . but at the end when i am configuration file for App Engine (needed to run the development web server):

> $ python deploy.py --generate-only --generate-test 1000

[image: this given me output like.]

and run development web server and run this code will give me error:

> $ ../google_appengine/dev_appserver.py .

error :-
[image: Error like this]

how to start development web server? can any one helo me?

Error:
[image: 3]

Comment: try to direct run dev_appserver.py

Comment: @PraveenSoni yes, it will be start but localhost can not start 8080 port. it display error like  
**This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: can you share or attach error screenshot in question, so people can understand

Comment: @PraveenSoni check this.. i am attached Error,

Comment: Share terminal error image also, where you start Dev app server

Comment: @PraveenSoni direct run **dev_appserver.py** and in terminal nothing to show any Error